# Accessing SQLite from another device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**Background:**

I don't have any knowledge in Android. I want to develop an app with 2 forms, one is to take customer data and one is to search the data. I can do this app in web or in Jface/SWT but just want to check feasibility of writing it in Android.

**Problem statement:**

Can we create an app in Android like mentioned above with SQLLite DB? but the data should be accessible from another android device with same app. i.e. my DB will be hosted on one Android device and I should be able to access that from another device also. The architecture is shown in below image.

Can we do something like this in android?
[image]

Comment: You need to serve your database on a network. Typically, you use a webService to consume the data from a database server.

Answer (score -1):

So I have two ways to do that:

1. Conver your csv file to db or sqlite using SQLite Database Browser and than paste this file into your assets folder of your project and than on create of your Application or Activity write it in the Data folder/directory of your app property and so that you can get your Database on each device.

If it does not help follow this one:

2. https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/remote-database-connector-rdc-connect-to-any-remote-db.31540/

Comment: So, you meant to say, we can remotely access SQLLite database stored on one device from other device, right?